# Value not retained if two different components are rendered using mutually exclusive rendered value

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I want to render only one of two different component which will have same value in the bean based a check box. I was able to do so using the rendered attribute but the values are not re-rendered, it gets reflected only when i invoke action. What am i missing here?

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.mask}">
     <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{Bean.mask}" execute="@form" render="@form"/>
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

<h:inputSecret id="id1" value="#{Bean.value}" rendered="#{Bean.mask}" redisplay="true"/>
<h:inputText id="id2" value="#{Bean.value}" rendered="#{!Bean.mask}"/>
```

PS: I am able to see the value in the bean. Only thing is the value is not updated in the text box or secret box.

Comment: try this <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{Bean.mask}" execute="@this" render="id1 id2"/>

Comment: I think the right event to use here is the `change` event and you can remove the listener, as this will do nothing. Are you actually recoginising that a ajax call is happening when you change the value of the checkbox?

Comment: Yes the listener method is invoked. I tried change event also but no use.

Comment: The view is not updated when the ajax call is triggered. I was able to update the view in the listener method for cases where these fields are available outside datatable. But the same is available inside datatable and iam not able to get the component of these fields. I was able to traverse to datable using view.findcomponent but how to access the inner components of the datatable..?